# R shiny dashboard, markdown knitr::kable grid lines are gone after upgrade

Tags: r, knitr, shinydashboard

I have R shiny dashboard application in which I render a R Markdown document ( it uses knitr::kable function to print a data table ) and include the resulting application using includeHTML in server.R and render it using uiOutput in ui.R

Recently upgraded packages to ( knitr : 1.12.3 ; shiny dashboard : 0.5.1 )

Now the rendered table in the shinydashboard output doesn't have grid lines, I'm not sure what caused it - any ideas?

Here is the relevant portion of the code from server.R :

```
 output$sae_text<-renderUI({
          req(input$sae_userids)
          render('myrmd.Rmd',output_dir=".",output_file="temp.html",params=list(subject=input$sae_userids))
          includeHTML("temp.html")
    })
```

Here is the relevant portion of the code from myrmd.Rmd :

````
 ```{r, results='asis',echo=FALSE}
  knitr::kable(ex4)}
 ```
````

Here is the relevant portion of the code  from ui.R  :

```
  tabItem(tabName="SAE",
          fluidRow(box(width=12,uiOutput("sae_text"))),
          ),
```

Comment: Funny thing is if I open temp.html in chrome directly I see the table grid lines.

Comment: rather than 'relevant' portions of code, can you post complete code that reproduces your issue, that other people can use directly?

Answer (score 0):

I found an issue with the latest rmarkdown package version 0.9.5. 
When I replaced this package with older version 0.8.1 then grid lines started to appear. It was reported to Rstudio support team.